# Combining and Adding Contents of 3 Columns

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, google-query-language

I am setting up a new Sheet to do some inventory tracking. I need the sum of the third column to add if the previous 2 columns are the same.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HQ_HVa2vtxi241-jtJ5zc-j2IWQRSDmBLVueOQDsUCM/edit?usp=sharing

Results should look like the output section.

[image: 0]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=QUERY(A3:C, 
 "select A,B,sum(C) 
  where C is not null 
  group by A,B 
  label A'REF',B'LOT',sum(C)'QTY'", 0)
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thank you for looking this over! This worked perfectly and is code that will be very valuable to me!